# Angular: How to filter in views with JSON values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, filter

I'm looking to see why a very simple Angular filter isn't working for me in example. Everything I've found online points to this format but it doesnt seem to work. 
Basically, I just want the information for the array that contains the value "completed" as the status. Here's my code:

```
<div class="span12" id="trainingWidget" ng-controller = "trainingInfo">
      <div class="span3 pull-right">
        <h4 class="theme-color">Available Courses</h4>
        <table id="courseList">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Location</th>
              <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in training | limitTo : 6">
              <td>{{item.location}}</td>
              <td>{{item.date}}</td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="span3 pull-right">
        <h4 class="theme-color">Your Last Course</h4>
        <div id="courseStatus">
          <p ng-repeat="item in training | limitTo: 1 | filter: {status: completed}">Was completed on <span id="recentTrainingDate">{{item.completionDate}}</span><br />
            <span id="recentTrainingTitle">{{item.name}}</span></p>
          <p class="theme-color">STATUS</p>
          <p><i class="icon icon-ok"></i> Up To Date</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the JSON:

```
[
    {
        "location": "Cincinnati, OH",
        "date": "Feb 18, 2016",
        "name": "ABC Certification",
        "status": "future",
        "completionDate": ""
    },
    {
        "location": "Houston, TX",
        "date": "Mar 1-3, 2016",
        "name": "123 Certification",
        "status": "future",
        "completionDate": ""
    },
    {
        "location": "Cincinnati, OH",
        "date": "Apr 26-28, 2016",
        "name": "Master Trainer Certification",
        "status": "future",
        "completionDate": ""
    },
    {
        "location": "Houston, TX",
        "date": "May 15-17, 2016",
        "name": "ABC Certification",
        "status": "future",
        "completionDate": ""
    },
    {
        "location": "Cincinnati, OH",
        "date": "July 12-14, 2016",
        "name": "123 Certification",
        "status": "future",
        "completionDate": ""
    },
    {
        "location": "Houston, TX",
        "date": "Sept 28-29, 2016",
        "name": "Birkman Method&reg; Certification Training",
        "status": "future",
        "completionDate": ""
    },
    {
        "location": "Houston, TX",
        "date": "Nov 9-11, 2015",
        "name": "Birkman Method&reg; Certification Training",
        "status": "completed",
        "completionDate": "July 15, 2015"
    }
]
```

I dont think its nessessary but here is the controller snippet:

```
myBirkman.controller('trainingInfo', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', function($scope, $http, $filter) {
    $http.get('assets/js/lib/angular/trainingData.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.training = data;

    });
}]);
```

The first ng-repeat works perfectly, but on the second repeat, I just want to show the first array that contains "completed" as the value of "status". Thanks in advanced for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'completed'` should be a string:

```
{status: 'completed'}
```

Otherwise it will search for `$scope.completed`.

Comment: Thanks but even with the single quotes, it still isn't working.

Comment: Ahh, my apologies. THis is the correct answer. My issue was that the only item that contains that value is the last one. I thought LimitTo: 1 would limit it to only items that have that value, not 1 of the total items. The first item has null for the value of completionDate.

Comment: Good to hear! I think you want to put the `limitTo` filter after the `filter` filter, then it will limit only the ones that pass the first filter (`limitTo`). Like this: `item in training | filter: {status: 'completed'} | limitTo: 1`